# Using Foreach Loop inside of Invoke

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

**Don't mind the variables like GameObject. Those are custom variables of mine.**

I have a thread, and I need to access a list variable inside the UI thread.

```
public void MainLoop(){
        while (true)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>


            foreach(GameObject ob in mygame.scenes[CurrentScene].objects){

              //run code here

            }


            ));
        }

    }
```

This throws the error, ***"} expected"***. I cannot seem to figure out how to fix this. Does anyone know how to run a foreach loop inside a Control Invoke?

Comment: Can't you just put an additional brace around the foreach loop, similar to `new MethodInvoker(() => {...});`?

Comment: Leaving aside the syntax error, this strikes me as extremely dangerous. **Lists are not threadsafe in C#**.  What are you doing to ensure thread safety?

Comment: @EricLippert nothing really.

Comment: Well then you should expect to have a program that crashes randomly or loses user data.

Comment: Fun! I will torture the masses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an additional set of {}.  Here your code is formatted so it is readable with the braces added.

```
public void MainLoop()
{
  while (true)
  {
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                {
                  foreach(GameObject ob in mygame.scenes[CurrentScene].objects)
                  {
                    //run code here
                  }
                }
                ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is the documentation page that explains what a lambda is, as you can see if it is not an expression then you need the brackets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions